# Writing lines to a csv file in a for loop in python

Tags: python, loops, csv, for-loop, writer

I have a large csv file with about 5000 rows in it. 
The first column contains identifying names for each row i.e. LHGZZ01  The first 9 rows have LHGZZ01 as a name the next 10 have something else and so on. 
There is no pattern as such so I used np.unique to find the index where the name changes.

I want to write a loop which will write each row of the source csv to new csv files only containing the same names in a loop.

```
datafile = open('source.csv','rb')
reader = csv.reader(datafile)
data = []
idx = []
dataidx = []
next(reader, None)#skip headers
for row in reader:
    d = row[0]
    idx.append(d)
    data.append(row)
    dataidx.append(row[0])

index =np.sort(np.unique(idx,return_index=True)[1])

nme = []#list of unique names
for row in index:
    nm = data[row][0]
    nme.append(nm) 

for i in np.arange(0,9):
    with open(str(out_dir)+str(nme[0])+'.csv','w') as f1:
        row = data[i]
        writer=csv.writer(f1, delimiter=',')#lineterminator='\n',
        writer.writerow(row)
```

The code above writes the first row of the new csv and stops.

My question is how to I loop through the source.csv file splitting the data after every new name change and then write the rows with the same row name to a unique csv?

Apologies for the long winded question but this problem is beyond my python skills unfortunately and is driving me nuts.

Any help or suggestions greatly appreciated

Sample csv:

```
Sample csv<br/>
ID  NORTH_DMS   EAST_DMS    DIST    <br/>
LHGZZ01 403921  374459  12500m  <br/>
LHGZZ01 403610  353000  12500m  <br/>
LHGZZ01 404640  360400  12500m  <br/>
LHGZZ01 404515  361900  12500m  <br/>
LHGZZ01 411240  381900  12500m  <br/>
LHGZZ01 415629  400600  12500m  <br/>
LHGZZ01 401503  384400  12500m  <br/>
LHGZZ01 400319  382200  12500m  <br/>
LHGZZ01 403921  372800  12500m  <br/>
LHGZZ02 412000  353200  12500m  <br/>
LHGZZ02 412749  343200  12500m  <br/>
LHGZZ02 403111  353000  12500m  <br/>
LHGZZ02 400600  374459  12500m  <br/>
LHGZZ02 401818  400600  12500m  <br/>
LHGZZ02 401525  393100  12500m  <br/>
LHGZZ02 401605  392400  12500m  <br/>
LHGZZ02 412000  384400  12500m  <br/>
LHGZZ02 372912  382157  8400m   <br/>
GPPHA01 381500  382200  8400m   <br/>
GPPHA01 393000  375252  8400m   <br/>
GPPHA01 395400  370602  8400m   <br/>
GPPHA01 401503  372912  8400m   <br/>
GPPHA01 400831  382157  8400m   <br/>
GPPHA01 390651  365700  8400m   <br/>
GPPHA01 372912  382954  8400m   <br/>
GPPHA02 392130  370602  12500m  <br/>
GPPHA02 400319  364000  12500m  <br/>
GPPHA02 400831  361900  12500m  <br/>
GPPHA02 390651  365700  12500m  <br/>
GPPHA02 382157  400600  12500m  <br/>
GPPHA02 382200  401818  12500m  <br/>
GPPHA02 375252  401525  12500m  <br/>
GPPHA02 385112  401605  12500m  <br/>
GPPHA02 392020  400319  12500m  <br/>
GPPHA02 392130  392130  12500m  <br/>
GPPHA03 392020  392020  9800m   <br/>
GPPHA03 385112  383000  9800m   <br/>
GPPHA03 382954  400600  9800m   <br/>
GPPHA03 365700  364000  9800m   <br/>
GPPHA03 381900  372912  9800m   <br/>
GPPHA03 383000  380700  9800m   <br/>
GPPHA03 392020  373724  9800m   <br/>
GPPHA03 385112  363842  7500m   <br/>
VVDFB01 374459  361210  12500m  <br/>
VVDFB01 353000  360002  12500m  <br/>
VVDFB01 360400  360002  12500m  <br/>
VVDFB01 361900  364000  12500m  <br/>
VVDFB01 381900  360002  12500m  <br/>
VVDFB01 400600  360002  12500m  <br/>
VVDFB01 384400  361210  12500m  <br/>
VVDFB01 382200  350530  12500m  <br/>
VVDFB02 372800  344400  12500m  <br/>
VVDFB02 353200  343100  12500m  <br/>
VVDFB02 343200  351448  12500m  <br/>
VVDFB02 353000  360002  12500m  <br/>
VVDFB02 374459  364000  12500m  <br/>
VVDFB02 400600  351448  12500m  <br/>
VVDFB02 393100  345353  12500m  <br/>
VVDFB02 392400  341731  12500m  <br/>
```

Comment: I think you've put your code in twice... (looks duplicated at a quick glance)

Answer (score 4):

Every time you open the file in `w` mode, it will overwrite everything that was there.  You should open the file one time, then loop over calls to `writerow` like:

```
with open(str(out_dir)+str(nme[0])+'.csv','w') as f1:
    writer=csv.writer(f1, delimiter=',')#lineterminator='\n',
    for i in np.arange(0,9):
        row = data[i]
        writer.writerow(row)
```

instead of reopening the file each iteration through the `for` loop

Comment: Thanks for the answers appreciate it. I was opening the file in the loop to try and incorporate it into a larger loop so I could open a new file after some number of iterations through the loop for each csv file with a new name. Not working out that way for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just to finish off the question above.

I solved my problem (not very elegantly) by opening/writing all the csv files I needed with the w attribute. Then used the a attribute to append each csv file within a second for loop.

Thanks for the answers

Cheers